# Regex works in javascript but not in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have a regexp to check email addresses that works in Javascript:

```
var re = /^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/; 
"any.address@gmail.com".search(re); // returns 0
```

But when I use preg_match() in PHP, using the same regexp and email it doesn't work!

```
$re = "/^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/";
echo preg_match($re,"any.address@gmail.com");
// echoes 0 - not 1!!
```

**EDIT**

Okay, so I have to add more detail.

The full code is here:

```
    $re = '/^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w\+\%\#\!\$\'\*\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/';

    if(is_array($recipients)){
        for($i=0;$i<count($recipients);$i++){
            echo preg_match($re,$recipients[$i]) . " - " . $recipients[$i] . "<br />";
        }
    }
```

When I just do the preg_match() (outside of the for loop), it will match the pattern properly. But if it's in this loop, then it won't validate!

Comment: No `foo+bar@example.com`? (Not to mention `%`,`_` *et al.*) I'm a moderately sad panda.

Comment: Well that's odd. [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/JHuqs) seems to disagree.

Comment: Sorry piskvor, added support for a few more symbols according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax

Comment: Use a `foreach`, and consider `filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` instead. Your list of addresses most likely contains a linebreak or something. Give us a var_dump().

Comment: Thank you mario! There was extra whitespace in the email addresses after the first one. I will use filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) in place of preg_match in this case

Comment: @mario Would you mind posting your solution as an answer so I can close this question? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's commonly advised to use PHPs builtin regex for email validation, which has broader coverage of syntax variations:

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

See [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var).
But btw, [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/filter_validate_email) is implemented using a regex too. See https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L522 for that.

Not relevant for the whitespace issue you originally had, though.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, as it is the *correct* way to validate an email. This, coupled with the `trim()` solution, solved my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're forgetting that backslashes have special meaning in PHP when used within a double-quoted string.

Have you even `echo $re;` just to confirm the patter is what you *expect* it to be? I recommend switching to a single-quoted string for the pattern, or make sure you escape every `\`.

```
$re = "/^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/"
$re = '/^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/';
```

BTW, as others have mentioned, it [does return 1](http://www.ideone.com/gcPqZ).

*I thought I would bring up escaping as it (even if not in this instance) can or will be an issue with patterns when in double quotes.*

Comment: That's only partially correct. For invalid escape sequences, PHP returns the input. `echo "\w"` actually outputs "\w".

Comment: @LinusKleen: Agreed, I've added a bit more explicit message to the bottom of my answer, but thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I echoed it and it's what I expected. I switched to single quotes, still no go.

Comment: @Martin: It has to be something on your end. I tried it (and posted the demo from ideone) that results in 1. Are there any other moving parts?

Comment: @Martin:What's recipients hold for information? Any spaces (maybe run it through a `trim()` before testing?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes so escape characters are ignored.

```
$re = '/^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/';
preg_match_all($re, 'any.address@gmail.com', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($arr);
```